# Bar Button not showing on the Navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

[image]i have a NAV VC on the left and a tableview controller connected to it. There is a segue to the left of the NAV VC (as shown on the screenshot. [image]

It goes fine to the View Controller that goes through the Navigation controller. but the bar button doesn't show.. Any ideas ? So the right hand pink cog doesn't show. the segue left of the navigation controller is a MODAL one, that gets called by

```
 [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SetUptoMain" sender:self];
```

thanks 
[image]
Even if i add a normal button in, it still doesn't work!!

Comment: can you post the whole storyboard image

Answer (score 0):

The way UIBarButtonItem works is that only the image's alpha channel is used for the button. You're not going to get a pink cog because you use a pink image; you're going to get a pink cog if you use an image that has an alpha value of 1 for the pixels you want to be pink, and 0 for the other pixels, and you set the tint color of the UIBarButtonItem.

Try just making the button a regular text button in the storyboard, and see if it shows up. If it does fine, then create a new button image as I've described above, and see if it shows up. You could also just try clicking the right button and see if it navigates even if you don't see it, because it's probably just showing up all white, or all the same color as your navigation bar.

Comment: Thats good info mate, but I have already tried just normal text and it doesn't work either!! It is driving me insane!

Comment: and the title image appears fine?

Comment: you mean the logo ?? Yeah but thats not in the Navigation bar, its an image file over the top of it.. As you can see from the recent picture upoad I have just tried to add an + (default button) and it still doesn't show nor tap...

Comment: ok, i'm not quite sure what else to do to reproduce it. is your title image just a small image, and doesn't cover the whole navigation title? if you right click on the navigation item on the side panel, does it show that the rightBarButtonItem is linked to the bar button? if you programmatically add a right barbutton item in viewDidLoad, does it appear? just a few things i'd play around with, given no clear answer.